# Most efficient way to read BGRA frame into multiple (B, G, R, A) buffers?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to unpack a BGRA 32bit frame into B, G, R, and A slices that are provided to me? I have a rudimentary function but the performance is poor. The source is a BufReader of a file.

Is there a faster way? Is there a specific SIMD instruction that I can use to do this?

My function:

```rust
fn read_bgra_frame<R: Read>(&mut self, source: &mut R) -> Result<(), Error> {
    let bounds = self.bounds();
    let b = self.b();
    let g = self.g();
    let r = self.r();
    let a = self.a();
    let crop_h = bounds.crop_height as usize;
    let crop_w = bounds.crop_width as usize;
    let pitch = bounds.pitch as usize;

    let mut bytes = source.bytes();
    for i_h in 0..crop_h {
        let offset = i_h * pitch;
        for i_w in 0..crop_w {
            let offset = offset + i_w;
            b[offset] = bytes.next().unwrap().unwrap();
            g[offset] = bytes.next().unwrap().unwrap();
            r[offset] = bytes.next().unwrap().unwrap();
            a[offset] = bytes.next().unwrap().unwrap();
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: You'd think it'd be easier to read this into a buffer of size 4N and then collate that data into your various planes. I'm not sure SIMD can help you here, it's a matter of cutting *way* down on how much overhead you have on the reading part. For example, you could read the whole thing in one shot if you knew what size to expect, which you should given you're using a raw bitmap form.

Comment: To expand a bit on what tadman said: Every `b[offset]` and `.unwrap()` might panic. So, you have to do 12 panic checks in your inner loop. These are likely way more expensive than whatever actual mov instructions are emitted. Instead of directly worrying about SIMD, write code that handles a chunk of data branch-free and check the generated asm. Might look like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=acbcc08069da19c1f2084bc1122b31c7), but it's hard to experiment without a definition of self. [See also](https://www.nickwilcox.com/blog/autovec/).